# Why is my score variable not assessable outside my GameScreen class?

Tags: java, swing, class, netbeans, protected

DIFFERENT CLASSES

```
package battleship;


public class GameSum extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public GameSum() {
        initComponents();
        J_time.setText(score);
    }



package battleship;

public class GameScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    protected int score;

    public GameScreen() {
        initComponents();

    }   
private void B_checkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

       if (score < getHS(0) && score < hs[1])  {setHS(0, score, nickname);  }
       for (int loop = 0; loop<5; loop++)
       {
       if(score > hs[loop] && score < hs[loop+1]) {setHS(loop+1, score, nickname); }   
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your variable is not public, or doesn't have a public getter available.

In Gamescreen just do:

```
public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
```

And call this function in GameSum.

By the way, I don't want to sound rude, but if this is your real indentation/code convention, it is really unredeable.
Try to indent properly, put the content of a if on a new line if you use braces, or on the same line without braces if it is a one line block. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

You should lean about `access modifiers` presidency in Java. You have to create a way to access your variable(create `public` seter and `public` getter) or make variable `public`.

Follow this link to refer about [access modifiers](http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/).

Answer (score 0):

Your score variable is `protected`, which mean it is only can access by (`Gamescreen`)it childs classes and classes on same package
and please go through on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/215505/2291134

Comment: I started with it as a public variable and it didn't work, anyway the score variable is in the same package so it should be accessible from another class in the same package but it isn't.